# Battery not working/charging but detected

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

i have a thinkpad t 410 and ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed. everything worked fine for a long time, but since a week or so my battery is not working properly any more (orange battery light flashing) it says it's on 97% and not charging. when i unplug the AC the cumputer turns off. i bought a new battery right away because i need it anyway but it's the same problem. i did a "hardware reset" (shut down, unplug AC, remove battery, press and hold power for 45 secs, plug in AC, turn on,shut down, connect battery) but thats not working,
and i booted ubuntu with bootparameter "apci=off" but that did not help ether.
here is what upower shows (battery 1)

[image]

and here battery two

[image]

has anyone got an idea what is going on?

Comment: I have a similar problem.  I had to buy an external charger to charge my laptop's battery directly with.  It's a pain, but it's better than nothing and likely cheaper than getting your motherboard replaced or buying a new system.

Comment: hmmm...that sounds interesting. i still have warranty for the laptop. i'll call customer support and post if it's a hardware issue or not. thanks for the answer.

Comment: ok so i got back my laptop from repair but apparently there was nothing from with it. both batterys were dead, even the new one. they gave me another battery and everthing works fine again.